# HttpWebRequest parse bot protected site

Tags: .net, vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

i am trying to parse a website with bot protection using vb.net HttpWebRequest.

currently my code is as below:

```
cookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
        httpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(urlbase & page), HttpWebRequest)
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 7.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.9 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"

        webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        result = New System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.[Default]).ReadToEnd()
```

but in the response it say that i have been marked as a bot prompting me with a captcha to prove i'm not. 
It also states: 
"Possible reason why this happend : 
You dont have javascript or cookies enabled 
You have a virus and your ip is listed in ProjectHoneypot 
You are making more than 100 requests per second to the site 
You, or a virus on your pc are/is faking your user-agent and pretending to be a search engine"

MY ip is not listed in projecthoneypot, i am not making more than 1 request per minute.
So i am guessing the problem would be javascript & cookies or the user-agent.

Comment: Have you tried different UserAgent strings? Alternately, have you manually evaluated the URL's code to determine if there are any scripts performing redirects that you may be unaware of? There could be any number of "security measures" implemented which would be impossible to determine without knowing the URL you're trying to access.

Comment: I opened the page in the browser and got the same prompt, i then entered the captcha and entered the site. after this i could run my code for about 5 times untill it happened again, now i dont get the prompt when i open in browser however. so there should not be a redirect or anything like that.

Comment: That sounds like its a problem with the website making false positives, rather than a problem with your code. If it happens in browser too, you're going to have to figure out a way to defeat/bypass it first and then implement that in your program.

Comment: I was able to bypass it using "webbrowser.Navigate(uri)
            Do Until webbrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Or webbrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive
                Application.DoEvents()
            Loop
            htmlstring = webbrowser.DocumentText" however this is rather slow, any ideas?

Comment: Do you still require help on this issue? What is the website/url that you are trying to access? The issue has something to do with the headers you are sending (or rather the lack of proper headers) and differs from site to site so we will need to know which website it is to provide any real help.

Comment: after some studying of the javascript i found that it was setting a cookie there. so i was able to finnaly fool the botchecker by parsing the javascript and setting my cookie.